# Flutter/Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web

I have an app that runs fine on Android, but when I try to start it for Flutter Web, I get

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: [core/no-options] Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source..` The stack trace doesn't go far enough back to point to a spot in my code.

```
void main() async {
  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // I've tried moving this after
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: "---",
    options: FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.apiKey,
        appId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.appId,
        messagingSenderId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.messagingSenderId,
        projectId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.projectId),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

If I remove `initializeApp()`, the app starts to load, and I get a different ear for Firebase not being configured.

if I wrap delay it, like so, it delays the error for 5 seconds, so it's definitely this line

```
void main() async {
  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: "---",
      options: FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.apiKey,
          appId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.appId,
          messagingSenderId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.messagingSenderId,
          projectId: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform.projectId),
    );
  });
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5), () async {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  });
}
```

Comment: Have you configured web platform as well with `flutterfire configure`? After `firebase_options.dart` is generated, the initalization in Dart should be like: `await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);`

Answer (score 4):

The solution for me was to remove the name Attribute. Apparently it's a recurring bug in the package.

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/10228

> I just ran the example in FlutterFire - FirebaseCore/Example. This
> works just fine!
>
> I narrowed down the issue to the following: Our application works just
> fine when I remove the name parameter from the initialization call.
> However when I add this I get the error message from above.
>
> Looks to me like somewhere in firebase_auth_web.dart it defaults to
> the default app.